# Recover from interrupted partition move

Tags: fedora, partition, ntfs, gparted

So, I was trying to shift my (NTFS) data partition to the right to accommodate expanding my boot partition. I was using gparted on a Fedora 20 live USB; about 230/560 GB in I closed my laptop, forgetting that would put it to sleep (I have that disabled in Windows). So, I opened it back up and I believe the kernel panicked; I saw a brief white flash and now the screen is just dark (although on). I'm hoping that since it was a move to the right, the data should all still be intact, but I don't really know how to proceed. Can gparted recover from this? What's the best course of action?